# Please notify us when a question we ask or answer is closed or reopened

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, closed-questions, reopened-questions

This would go in the recent activity page.

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on both [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) and [reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402476/51) events.

Answer (score 8):

This makes perfect sense. I would also possibly suggest one of those orange bar notifications on the fly, but I know how much you hate those.

**Edit** I should clarify that I am talking about the orange bar notifications for things like badges that appear on the top of the screen, not the idiot envelop flashy thing.

Comment: I do hate those because it doesn't work. For one thing I'll go to my responses tab and then questions and it'll light up. I'll go back and see it's lit up about something I'e seen already. Plus it lights up for CW votes, which I don't see.

Comment: I'm talking about one of those great big orange bars...not the envelope flasher.

Comment: Don't you hate those too, cletus?

Comment: Oh right, the notification bars. Yeah that makes more sense.

Comment: I love you cletus.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the notifications bars is that you do not see them unless you're on the effected Stack Exchange site. My suggestion would be to add an "alert" type to the existing "comment" and "answer" types in the inbox list. The first time a user clicks an alert, give them the option to opt-out of getting the alert messages across all sites, or from a list of the sites.

Comment: At the time this suggestion was first posed, there was no "inbox" to drop it in. Now that there is, it's worth re-visiting this particular issue as it would still be good to know and there is a better, less annoying way to notify users that something has been closed/re-opened.