# Should available close votes be a function of inflation or rep?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I've noticed that my allotment of close votes on SO no longer lasts as long as it used to. Maybe it's because there are so many more migration paths, maybe there are many more poor questions (more users means more questions and more questions means more poor questions), or maybe I'm just getting more curmudgeonly in my old age.

Regardless, it seems that reducing the domain of the site (fewer things are on-topic) should make more available close votes. And an increasing number of new users (most of whom ask poor questions or just dupes) would seem to indicate that a larger pool of close votes is needed. Lastly, as users gain more experience (either more rep or just hanging around for a longer duration), they also gain the knowledge of which questions have been asked before (better able to find dupes), indicating that they should have more close votes.

So my suggestion is that the number of available close votes increase based on one of:

- the number of close options (including migration paths -- 2 for each?)
- the number of users (distribute extra votes evenly among eligible voters)
- the rep of the voter (perhaps 1 vote per 1000 rep)

Comment: Or possibly, they could increase based on the individual closer's past history, much like has been recently implemented for flagging. If questions that you vote to close are frequently closed (meaning 4 other users agreed with you), you're obviously voting to close in the appropriate circumstances, and your daily allotment of close votes could increase accordingly.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, that's a good idea too. I didn't suggest it, though, out of fear that it would encourage too much closing. I'm all for it if other people don't mind.

Answer (score 34):

The default # of close votes per day is 12.

I just noticed that SU and SF have been at 24 close votes per day per user since ... well, forever.

I'm going to go ahead and make 24 close votes per day the new default network-wide to start, and meanwhile it has been set to 50 for SO.

Answer (score 18):

It's now Monday in many parts of the world.  In some places, it's morning, while it's the early afternoon elsewhere.  Regardless, it's that time again.  *They* are here.  The [Bad Askers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616620/how-to-auto-increment-a-variable-using-session) have [arrived again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617680/integrate-project-into-local-host) to [terrorize the citizens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616880/json-decode-in-php) of SO.

But I am also here.  Well, not in a few minutes, as I'm freaking tired and am going to bed, but that's not the point.

The point is that I only have a few close votes left before midnight UTC rolls over again, and I fear that there will be many, many more questions on which they could be used.

There's been a lot of buzz lately about stopping bad questions.  Giving high-rep non-moderators **a (slightly) larger pool of close votes could go a long way towards keeping things cleaner**.

Even just **splitting out close-as-dupe votes** from the rest of the close types would give us more leeway to close the unsalvageable questions and point the duplicates elsewhere.

Comment: +1 For the "terrorizing" part. XD

Comment: I love the "how can integrate my project in to local host .. plz any solve this.." question!

Comment: well, fwiw, see my answer. We will look at this again next week when the team is back from MIX.

Comment: When you go to bed, those of us that already have Monday will get up instead. We too have votes, so have faith!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it should. [I want to have more than 50 Close Votes per day!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158833/i-want-to-have-more-than-50-close-votes-per-day)

> (Yes it's a bit childish to write I want and put an exclamation mark at the end, but it's rather straight)