# Increase vote to close count when higher rep

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should available close votes be a function of inflation or rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/should-available-close-votes-be-a-function-of-inflation-or-rep)

Can we increase the limit from 12 to some scale or fixed amount when your flag rate or reputation is high?

Comment: Can you tell why that would be particularly useful? Can you explain why you're not able to get what you want from what we have now? I understand the reason, but look, there's 30,000+ users on SO (10k+ pages of 36 users), and the first [134](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=134&tab=reputation&filter=all) pages worth can all vote to close. That's 57,888 potential close votes already. Only a few thousand questions get asked as is. What you really want is to encourage other users to close questions, so you need some way to raise that visibility.

Comment: @drachenstern Nicely analyzed. I particularly like looking to the solution that would better accomplish the same end goal. It would be interesting, though, to get an estimate on the percentage of those first-134-pages-users that are active on a given day.