# Let close voting from the review page not count towards your daily close voting cap

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unlimited close votes from flagged queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115497/unlimited-close-votes-from-flagged-queue)

On SO there is a steady number of close votes to be reviewed on [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) (59.3k). To review and possible help close these posts you would either need *a lot* of reviewers or *a lot* of time. I don't even think you will make it with a lot of time, because there will always be new posts added to the review list. You will need a lot of reviewers, because in the first place a questions needs multiple votes to either be closed or not and every reviewer only has a maximum number of votes per day (50 for me).

I think it is pretty much impossible to work on reviewing the list with that amount of daily votes. I am masochist and I follow tags with often terrible questions which makes sure I burn right through my 50 votes per day only by spending time on the site without even looking at the review page.

My suggestion is to (maybe temporarily) exclude close voting on the review page from the daily voting cap. I already posted an answer on [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/how-can-the-close-vote-review-queue-be-improved/145680#145680), but I thought I would add it as an [feature-request] so the community can decide whether it is just me who thinks this will help to trim down the close votes on the review page.

Comment: P.S. May I also not why it wouldn't be a good idea? :-)

Comment: [Nothing new under the sun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115497/unlimited-close-votes-from-flagged-queue) :)

Comment: @AdamRackis closing as dupe. However it still is a problem :) Maybe there is some other way of tackling this problem. Perhaps more close votes or something? Anyway closing as dupe.

Comment: Or maybe add votes not based on rep but based on followed tags :P

Comment: No arguments here.  Expanding the votes for use in the queue seems like a good idea to me :-)

Answer (score -2):

50 close votes a day is still a *lot*, even if you're reviewing a lot.  As great as it is to have people reviewing stuff in the queue, if you find yourself running out of close votes perhaps consider either contributing to the site in other ways (editing, asking/answering, etc.) or taking some time away from the site so you don't burn out on reviewing.

Also, if you see something that's particularly egregiously in need of closing after you've exhausted your close vote quota simply use a flag.

Comment: 50 is not that much if you spend some time in for example [php] or [javascript]. And dupes cannot be usefully edited.