# At what reputation does a user gain 100% maximum privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

While users unlock all possible privileges at 20,000 reputation, their privileges are still "enhanced" as their reputation increases. For instance,

- An [**additional delete vote**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) is granted per 1000 reputation.
- An [**additional flag**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) is granted per 2000 reputation.

Are there any other "enhanced" privileges out there that I am missing? It would be great if someone provided an exhaustive list of incremental privileges, as it's difficult to know for sure without sifting through the entire privileges help center page.

At what point does a user gain 100% access to all possible privileges on the site (i.e., the maximum # of delete votes, flags, etc.)?

Comment: I want to say "when they become a moderator" but I know a dev will soon come along and scoff at me.

Comment: When they become a developer :)

Comment: @ChrisF that is technically the correct answer. Or maybe, when you become Jeff Atwood :)

Comment: When you own a majority of stock in StackExchange Inc.

Comment: When you actually know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In theory, it'd have to be the **180k** reputation milestone.

At that point, you get 90 bonus flags for the maximum of 100 moderator flags each day, regardless of your flagging history. However, in practice this is (now) mostly meaningless because most of your bonus flags will come from your [flags that were deemed helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890) anyway, and you can get to 100 flags with just 15 rep.

Maxing out your delete votes however is based only on your reputation and happens a lot sooner than that: 30 votes at 35k reputation.

Comment: Nice to know that you still get some incremental privilege enhancements above 20K rep.

Comment: Are there any milestones between 20K and 180K?

Comment: @ɹǝʞɐʇıɥʍʍǝɹpuɐ Depending on your flag weight, the 100 flags milestone is anywhere between 180k and 116k, and there's the 30 delete votes at 35k.

Comment: So delete votes and flags are the only additional privileges after 20k? There's nothing else that you can gain privilege-wise?

Comment: @AlexLockwood No, (as of writing) 20k unlocked the last privilege, "Trusted User".

Comment: @vcsjones, No it's not. You get additional delete votes and flags even after 20k. Did you read my question?

Comment: My question remains: is there anything else left to gain other than delete/flag votes after 20k? For example, close votes, up/down votes, etc.?

Comment: @AlexLockwood I don't think so, else I would've mentioned those. Probably some anti-abuse/rate limiting mechanics take your rep into account, but we can't really pinpoint specifics. I know there is a point at <=101 rep where the spam filter lets you post spam if you solve a CAPTCHA first.

Comment: Scaling the number of close votes [has been suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/should-available-close-votes-be-a-function-of-inflation-or-rep) @Alex, but is not currently implemented.

Comment: If it all seems meaningless above 20k, perhaps you can delete your account and start over?

Comment: @BoPersson: No need to delete the account. Just donate reputation via Bounties.

Answer (score 7):

The [algorithm for number of helpful flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185907/184179) has changed to make it **much** easier to reach the full 100 flags (I have maxed out on SO at only 17k):

- Having 25k reputation and 780 net helpful flags,
- Having 35k reputation and 730 net helpful flags,
- Having 180k reputation and zero net helpful flags.

The latter two max out delete votes (for 100% privileges).

Comment: I've maxed out on SO with 1.7k rep from recommend closure flags.

Answer (score 1):

Once the new dupehammer feature was introduced, there's now a new threshold for having maximum privileges: once one has a gold badge for at least one tag used by every question on the site, it becomes possible for them to bindingly close as duplicate *any* question on the site or reopen *any* question on the site closed as a duplicate.

This would be difficult/impossible to earn on main Q&A sites especially given that tag badges are only issued for tags used on at least 100 questions and some questions may have only tags for which badges aren't issued.

However, on *meta* sites, due to having required tags ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [support](/questions/tagged/support), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), or their localized equivalents on international site metas), these badges become *way* easier to earn, as once the meta site becomes more active each of those tags qualifies for badges way quicker. This also applies to sites with other sets of required tags (Stack Apps and Area 51 Discussions).

Therefore, the answer to "when do you gain maximum privileges" on a site with required tags is when one has a gold badge for all of the site's required tags - this will allow them dupehammer privileges on every question on the site.