# What after achieving 2K?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I enjoyed using [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) a lot. I spent hours on it: Editing, answering, and asking when I needed any help. I had **milestone** before my eyes each day. But after reaching 2K, I find it kind of boring.

**What are the milestones and interesting things that I can do after 2K** and hence I **keep on learning and working** on this community?

Comment: If you're here just for the rep, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Servy I never said anything about repo. I just wanted to know what are the next things after 2K. Sorry if I have miss lead

Comment: If you aren't talking about rep, then what have you reached two thousand of that is no longer motivating you to participate on the site?  It doesn't look like you've passed 2k answers yet.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges is the comprehensive answer to your question.

Comment: @WeaponofChoice *cough* why do you not answer with that, then?

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow Because it would be a link-only answer. :P

Comment: That's bound to happen on some MSE (Mxx) questions anyways ;) If the question asked is answered in the help-center, a useful answer **will** be a "link-only" answer with maybe some trivia...

Comment: @Weapon Vogel is right, you can post the link and quote some relevant parts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [At what reputation does a user gain 100% maximum privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136020/at-what-reputation-does-a-user-gain-100-maximum-privileges)

Comment: 10k, you can view all the spam messages and crybaby rants that get deleted on meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next milestone is reaching 10k reputation. This will unlock moderator tools for you, lots of fun.

Good luck, use Stack Overflow wisely, and don't abuse your powers. :)

Comment: What about close voting at 3k...?

Comment: @Steven good point, guess I was looking too far ahead... feel free to add that as new answer. :)

Comment: Approving tag wikis at 5k, that's my next target.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242715/what-after-achieving-2k#comment793326_242715 ;)

Comment: @Inf you're too modest! :)