# I want to have more than 50 Close Votes per day!

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question)
>   [Should available close votes be a function of inflation or rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83080/should-available-close-votes-be-a-function-of-inflation-or-rep)

I just was seeing that I hit a close-vote limit of 50 for today. When my reputation increases, will the number of close-votes per day also increase? [No it's said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question).

But I need more close-votes. Please consider to extend the limit depending on reputation.

E.g.:

- If a 3k User has 50 Votes
- Then a 10k User could have let's say 75 Votes
- And a 20K User should have about 100 Votes

and so on and so forth. Something so that it scales a bit up.

Comment: I don't believe it should scale up like that. Maybe a 10k user get 75 and a 20K gets 100... I think anymore increases the amount of damage capable by a rogue high-rep user, for very little gain.

Comment: @Earlz: Sure, that is exemplary. I might be even wrong with a 3k user 50 votes. I mean that sounds a bit high, e.g. 6k user 100 votes looks high to me. I edited the question so it's better reflected. I like the numbers you presented.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. 50 potential close votes is already quite a bit of influence a single user can have each and every day. I don't necessarily see a reason why we need to increase this.

Comment: @Bart: Take a look at the review queue. Also influence is limited because you have only one vote per question. And anyway, influence is not bad in this case, because the influence is equal across users.

Comment: And the close vote queue is steadily decreasing in size. Not going up. And yes, your vote can affect 50 individual questions each and every day. That seems more than enough to me.

Comment: Well all I can say is that I have days where that is not enough for me. That's all.

Comment: If you're wanting to close over 5 questions a day, you are almost certainly closing inappropriately. True to use judgment and you should never come close to 50.

Comment: @DavidThielen If you have access to the close votes review queue, or the 10K tools, it's no problem finding way more than five indubitably closeworthy questions a day. If you're willing to invest a serious bit of time, even 50 is no problem.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't have access to either (my score is a bit above 1.5K). But I have seen a lot of questions closed that I thought should not have been closed. My impression is some (NOT most) Moderators are eager to exercise their power by closing for any minor infraction of their strict reading of the criteria. But as I've said, I have not seen the close review queue.

Comment: @David Yes, before getting access to the queues, it's hard(er) to come across many closeworthy questions every day (though it's tag-dependent, if you follow [tag:php], there are habitually dozens per day that should be closed as duplicates alone). But for people who have, like hakre, your opening sentence is wrong, just pointing that out. As for closed questions that shouldn't have been closed [in whoever's opinion], yes, sure. In most cases, both positions can be held by reasonable people, so you'll have questions with the wrong state even if all close votes are judiciously cast/withheld.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think there's a problem when a question is in the "both positions can be held" category and it's closed. In my opinion, if in doubt, leave it open. What's hilarious about this is the person asking above to be able to close more questions - had his request closed. Hoisted on his own petard :)

Comment: @David But you can't, for every close vote, explore the question whether you can declare everybody thinking that question maybe should not be closed a raving lunatic, or whether that position can be held by reasonable people. So if _you_ are sure the question is a duplicate/off topic/not constructive/not a real question/too localized, you cast your vote. If not enough people agree, it'll stay open. If it's closed and enough people disagree, it will be reopened (could happen to this one, it has three reopen votes at the moment).

Comment: @DanielFischer - we might agree more than we disagree on what should be closed. My main point is that someone who wants more than 50 close votes/day is out of control.

Comment: @David I agree that 50 is enough, but then, like you, I spend my time in saner tags. hakre is a PHP person, and in that tag, I can see how one wishes for more.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, 50 is **not** enough. We were at 40k in February. Sure, 70k when we started, but now we're at 57k. The amount is **not decreasing**. I would happily take on more close votes and **no incentives** to get this number down. Simple maths - we don't have enough close votes to decrease the number effectively.

Comment: X-Ref: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171492/increase-close-votes-in-review