# Do we have a problem with follow-through on close votes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I've been looking at the review queues lately, and something has caught my eye. The close vote queue just keeps growing. It hit 50k just a little ago, and is well on its way to 51. I've never actually seen it go down. Do we have a problem with a huge influx of close votes, but no actual closes?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171492/increase-close-votes-in-review.  FWIW, on an active day, I usually run out of close votes before I even make it to the Close Vote Queue.

Comment: Only one in 5 close votes removes an item from the list where only 1 vote puts it into the list... I think the current state of the close queue is as expected...

Comment: It had been steadily going down for quite a while going as low as 47k at some point (I seem to remember). But the last few weeks it has only grown. I wonder what caused that.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Thanks for the link

Comment: @Lix: Is it supposed to be growing at a steady rate?

Comment: @lin - more posts are being created, more users are signing up... so I would say yes (to a certain extent).

Comment: @Bart: I wonder too. Is there any way that we can see the tag distrobution of the close votes tab? It might just be a spike of low quality in one of the big tags ([tag:ios], [tag:android], [tag:php], etc.)

Comment: @Lix, Bart: Feel free to put those into answers.

Comment: Agree with @Bart, but Let's clean it up :)

Comment: Just because something has a close vote on it does not mean that it needs to be closed. I don't know that we need to feel pressured to remove everything from this queue just because it is there. I've already seen a few cases where people piled on close votes for a good question just because it appeared in this queue. This might be the time to revisit discussions about [adding the ability to cast "don't close" votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close).

Comment: @BradLarson I was just writing something roughly to that effect. Doesn't the Leave Open button accelerate a Q's removal from the queue, and so works kind of like a Don't Close button? I think part of the problem is calling it a "queue" which implies that it _needs_ to be reduced to zero.

Comment: @joran - Yes, Shog's answer to the question I link has this wording: "a sufficient number of "Do Not Close" responses (currently 3) will kick the question out of the review queue," but I wonder if that's strong enough to combat the impulse of people wanting to close questions in this queue.

Comment: I wonder if the SO mod elections have had an effect here.  All of the people who've newly discovered that they have the ability to cleanup the site and want to start preparing for the next election.  I would have expected a bump in people using the review queues, more flags coming in, people adding close votes, etc.  I also would think it'd die down for the most part after a bit.

Comment: it's quite likely that reviewers "educated" by experience in CV queue start casting more CVs than before trying it. Someone who passed over few dozens of blatantly NC / NARQ posts while working in the queue, can develop a sense to recognize stuff like that when they see it outside of the queue. "Bad questions all feel alike; every good question is perceived in its own way." ([Leo Tolstoy](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/27719.html) - [gnat](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165773/gnat))

Comment: @Servy - Another suspicion is that some people who used to work the queues now spend their time moderating instead. :-)

Comment: IIRC it was shrinking by about a thousand every month...growing would be very concerning. But it's always been too big of a backlog

Comment: @BradLarson You'd probably get a lot more people helping out if you allowed users to [access a post's reviews from the post itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174789/158605), but that's been status-declined :( I know I'm quite willing to help out as I come across questions while browsing the site, but I am not usually interested in dedicating time go through the queues.

Comment: the problem has been (at last) acknowledged and addresed by SE team: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions "feature request at MSO")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I thought I'd try and get some data, but I'm not aware of a way to see the full history of reviews, short of scraping the 11000-odd pages on the History tab...  Here's a plot that for each day shows the ratio of number of posts that received their first close vote (and still remain unclosed now) versus the number of posts that were closed.  These are raw data from the Explorer.  I don't think there's a way to determine which of the posts that have pending close votes have left the review queue.

[image: Awaiting Closure/Closed for each day]

I'm not sure you can read much in to this, but it does look like the balance is shifting back to where it was in the middle of last year.  The low point in October appears to coincide with the end of the time when some reviewers were 'processing' over 100 items per day from the Close queue.  There's another dip in the winter holiday season.  The July dip is coincident with the  earliest reviews visible in the history tab - that may be a real coincidence though.

The 50K outstanding seems like a large number, but it's around 1% of the total.  There are only about 210K posts in total showing with non-null Close dates in the Data Explorer, of these 87K have Close votes visible - it appears the data are not complete.  About a quarter of the closed questions have fewer than five votes, which suggests that mod intervention was involved in those closures.

To me it seems all too tempting to rush and process the 'backlog' quickly, rather than accurately, and this certainly was happening back in October.  Many of the items in the backlog would, if posted now, be closed quite quickly. There are probably a significant number of old posts that are as worthy of closure, but just don't get the attention.

One observation on the rate limiting as it stands: If I review 40 items in the queue, and use my remaining 10 votes to add new items to the queue, I've at best made no impact that day on the total number of reviews 'outstanding'.  The ten items I added will likely need 40 review actions by others.

*Raw queries used.*

- Number of posts closed each day: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104050
- Number of posts with first vote raised each day: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/104089

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis!