# Apply filter to exclude particular tag in close vote queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review

In the review queue we have filter which allows us to quickly see the questions in which we have expertise in, which is great for productivity.

But here is a scenario, I have expertise in Java and a few Java related technologies. Now in the close vote queue I can add filter of Java but that will bring up all questions related to java.

But I need to ***exclude*** some particular tags from that filter. Is is possible? Or Should this be provided as a new feature?

Advantages to it will be even more productive voting. And as the close vote review queue is close to 76k, we need some rapid voting from the community.

Comment: +1. I just got close privileges, but will probably not use them as much as I otherwise would. The biggest tag associated with R (for a graphing package with its own syntax that I am not familiar with) attracts incredibly lame questions. No offense to package-author hadley and his documentation skills. The queue has grown by ~400/day since I started paying attention.

Comment: +1 Was just going through the close votes queue and found that I'd like this too.

Comment: Same here – for some reason, I keep getting a huge load of c# questions to review. I don’t know anything about c# (and have no intention to in the near future), so I keep skipping and skipping and thinking I should be able to just filter those out. Actually, I would be happy if the tag filters I have for displaying questions were just active for the review queue as well.

Comment: Three years later and it is still a feature we could use.