# A non-competitive, chat-based event for reviewing close-votes?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, community, events

### tl;dr

> *"Many hands make light work."*

[image]

Based on the belief that incentivizing moderation (*e.g.* close-votes reviews) via competition can undermine the integrity and quality of said moderation, this is a proposal for a *non-*competitive, camaraderie-focused community event, designed to chip away effectively at the review queue, without sacrificing quality.

Please scroll further down for more background. Otherwise:

### The Proposal

How about we hold a community event—call it a "Closing Party!" (or whatever<sup>*</sup>)—where

1. **we announce a date**—this "party" goes on for 24 hours,
2. **we allow more than the standard 40 daily close votes** during the party—

   - we can do away with the limit entirely,
   - or we can raise the limit to a higher number, *e.g.* 200,
   - or (admittedly, my preferred idea), we can restock more *frequently*, *i.e.* 40 votes *per hour*—which does away with any notion that this is a race, as all participants are limited to a set pace.
3. **and we announce a chat room specially made for the party**—with a bot that announces,

   - "At this rate, the queue will empty out on: July 13th, 2016!" (Mostly [for fun](http://xkcd.com/605/).)
   - "7,635 reviews completed so far by 524 participants! Amazing!"<sup>†</sup>
   - "Pekka 웃 just completed 40 reviews! Hold tight, Pekka 웃, your votes will restock in: 23m."

I don't want to overcomplicate this idea, but these do seem to be the minimum needs. The chat room and its bot, in particular, would glue the participants together.

I think this way it'll *really* feel like a team effort, with no pressure of competition (whether against other users or time), instilling a feeling of community instead. **I think participants might even be driven to ask about and discuss how to appropriately handle such and such ambiguous cases** (*e.g.* closing a wildly popular list question)—if only to have something to say in chat! It might also be an opportunity for others (including <3k rep users who can't yet review close votes) to read good (and bad) arguments, chime in, and maybe even earn some of those chat-related badges :-)

### Promotion & Misc.

To promote this event, I imagined we'd post an announcement on the community bulletin(s); and, unless it goes against our own guidelines, perhaps advertise in our profiles:

> Come to Stack Overflow's **"Closing Party!"** on **Friday, November 29th**! [link] Grab your favorite (soft-)drink, join the chat [link], and let's do some damage to that review queue. By the way, we're giving out the coveted Stack Exchange coffee mug [link] to 10 lucky participants!<sup>‡</sup> Copy this into your profile to spread the word.

<sup>* I'm not at all attached to "Closing Party!" being the name of this event. I'm also aware that "Closing Party!" might sound like Stack Overflow is shutting down (though, maybe that'll grab their attention ;-), which is in part why I keep stylizing "Closing Party!" with an exclamation point—to take away the seriousness. In any case, alternative suggestions are welcome.</sup>

<sup>† A "participant" would be a user who has logged into this chat room (joined the "party") and has reviewed at least one close-vote.</sup>

<sup>‡ I think prizes are acceptable if and only if they are awarded by lottery—otherwise, awarding by competition, again, might detract from the purpose.</sup>

#### Background (only for those interested in further discussion)

I actually didn't see @RobertHarvey's [Proposed contest for close review queue posse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse) until I logged in to write this post. I didn't mean to knock any *part* of his idea—I agree a contest *can* be great fun (and productive!)—and I agree we need a community effort—but, again, I felt a competition might not be appropriate for this *particular* purpose, namely, incentivizing an activity of *moderation*—an activity in which, IMHO, we should not trade integrity (*e.g.* tempt toward haste) for sake of, say, bringing the queue counter down.

The image of hundreds (if not thousands) of users, filters set and ready to click, competing against one another (and/or against time) to review as many items as possible for a chance to win something from a finite pool of rewards—doesn't gel with my idea of prudent moderation.

Even relieving competitive pressures by making rewards infinite (goal-based), I still feel that prizes, badges, and other such [extrinsic motivators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motivation#Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_motivation) may only serve to inject a "rush" of enthusiasm that'll quickly die out, replaced by the usual fatigue associated with reviewing the close-votes queue. (From [the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow) [threads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145665/how-can-the-close-vote-review-queue-be-improved) [I've](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176060/close-vote-review-queue-reorganization-proposal) [read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184312/suggestion-close-votes-review-queue), including [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183840/what-can-be-done-about-the-massive-close-votes-queue-on-stack-overflow) where @Mooseman proposed a similar idea as this, I've seen reviewing close-votes described as "hopeless," "futile," and "demotivating," in scattered comments.) Given such sentiment, offering *more* reward to do the same, unappealing work, might only lead to *more* tunnel-vision (a narrow focus on the reward) and *less* attention to integrity and efforts like editing to improve questions, thinking critically and voting against the crowd (*e.g.* taking the time to comment that a proposed duplicate is *not* actually a duplicate because of such and such a reason), and consulting Meta for appropriate actions in ambiguous situations.

If integrity *weren't* a concern, and only bringing down the queue counter *was*, then why not just implement one of the many robots / expiration schemes suggested in numerous past discussions? (See aforementioned links.) The tricky part, I think, is incentivizing *without* sacrificing integrity and quality.

Comment: Requests only, perhaps (only registered event people who are checked out to be okay reviewers to join)?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Sure, that could be a good (and safe) way to start. And if it turns out well, although now maybe I'm getting carried away, imagine we had _monthly_ Closing Party!s, eventually opening it up to all. (Though, still, only >3k rep could cast those close votes.)

Comment: "Review party"?

Comment: Clean-up party?

Comment: "Queue party"? For the Brits...

Comment: Gamification + Community = StackExchange. Count me in.

Comment: May I suggest "closing bee" instead? Many hands make light work etc. Think barn raising...

Comment: I know it would be good to get the close vote queue down in size but is it really a good idea to encourage people to speed through the queue rather then take time to ensure each question is properly one is properly reviewed first?

Comment: @JoeW - Exactly my point :-) _"IMHO, we shouldn't trade integrity, e.g. shouldn't tempt toward haste, for sake of, say, bringing the queue counter down."_ I am advocating _against_ competitive ideas that may encourage such speed-reviewing, in favor of (1) paced reviewing, (2) with an emphasis on discussion, and (3) prizes (if any should exist) that award by lottery for participation, _not_ for reviewing more/faster.

Comment: @acheong87 I would suggest a special bronze badge as a souvenir: each participants gets this special party badge.

Comment: Related: [SO Close Vote Reviewers chatroom](https://socvr.org/faq)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum - Ah yes, if only the OP thought to create such a room... (;