# Provide incentives for reviewing close votes in upcoming Winterbash 2013

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, vote-to-close, winter-bash-2013

#### [Winterbash](https://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) (hopefully) is coming up! [Meaning fun and hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash)!

We have a lot proposals how to reduce the close vote queue like a [close party](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203704/a-friendly-non-competitive-chat-based-community-event-for-reviewing-close-vot) or [free mugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse).

Why don't we put most attention to the *review system* and especially the *close-vote queue* in the Winterbash?

We could have

- the **best hats** for reviewing the close queue
- **surprise** review hats
- hats for knocking yourself out **10 days in a row** in the close vote queue
- hats for reviewing **all** queues
- **disqualification** (total or temporary) from *Winterbash* for too many wrong reviews
- an **extended period** of the Winterbash up to a month to get the queue empty (and have more fun)

What do you think?

<sub>Besides, this question contains a list of bolded words and mentions red freehand circles. So let's go for it!</sub>

Comment: One minor hesitation: would that merely get the queue empty, or get it reviewed properly as well?

Comment: That's why a disqualification would come in when failing reviews.

Comment: Shouldn't you get a dunce cap for too many wrong reviews?

Comment: Yes, I saw that @juergend. But I wonder if that's enough. If you're going to flood the review queues, I'd like them to do good reviews rather than chant "Hats, Hats, Hats". But maybe I'm a pessimist, and all I need is a hat to cheer me up.

Comment: Since hats are temporary and you can show only one at a time, they are less of an incentive than badges. I can see this proposal work. We would indeed need good review audits. Maybe some that are hand-picked by the mods, and can be re-used for different reviewers.

Comment: We need to see if Punion is up for another Punion hat.

Comment: I thought we were never going to repeat that mistake again...

Comment: @S.L.Barth - I don't know. Plenty of people spammed Meta with pretty poor questions last December just to get a hat, so temporary or not some people are going to try to game the system to get this meaningless token.

Comment: There just might be all-new hats this year...

Comment: Ah... I see we are on the [same wavelength](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208248/191410) here... why wait for Winter Bash, though?

Comment: It would appear the SE team doesn't care for the review queue.

Comment: Isn't this basically suggesting exactly what I suggested to bad response in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209147/functionality-for-proposing-community-drives-or-initiatives

Answer (score 15):

This doesn't really sound like much fun to me. Particularly the "disqualification" part. After seeing several contests that had to involve some sort of punishment for folks who went nuts trying to cheat, I've pretty much lost my appetite for any contest that has to be *vigilantly policed* in order to not fall apart; really sours the whole deal.

WinterBash is a nice way to unwind at the end of the year by passing out temporary tokens for good stuff that folks are doing *anyway*; let's try to stay focused on that.

Answer (score 7):

Another great idea to encourage people to visit the review queue.

At this point I'd just give this *short term solution* to clear the review queue a **GO** already! Let's try it and see what happens.

If 80K questions gets reviewed - good or bad that still leaves us with the increase in the % of people who are going to come back to the queue in the future.

Suppose that

70% of the reviews are going to be good - the remaining bad 30% will most likely re-enter the review queue at some point in time... Since after the *big party* we are going to have much better *educated* and *experienced* reviewers this should not be a problem.

That's just what I think you're cool to disagree

Comment: I think it's not a bad idea - they aren't getting closed at any rate being in the queue, so why not?

Answer (score 1):

It may not have been the main focus, but there are ***`six`*** hats that you can get from reviewing. Six! I think that this is also affecting the review queue. It peaked out at roughly 107k and it is now down to less than 100k! I think these hats have been a success, and it would also be nice if in the future we could give incentives to users to visit these queues.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, the reason that the CV queue went down is also due to a bug that CV didn't age. This was fixed, and so every night at 3:00 AM UTC CV's age, taking questions out of the CV queue that now have 0 CV.

Comment: @hichris123 - Do you have a link to a post on that?

Comment: The messages around this one, mainly the ones by Anna and Shog are relevant. http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1683360#1683360

Comment: @hichris123 - Haha, that is a good conversation. Thanks for the insight :)