# WinterBash 2013

Tags: discussion, fun, winter-bash-2013

Last year's Winter Bash looked like a success from my point of view.
Any info on what we are getting for Christmas this year ?

[image: A unicorn pulling a sled full of toys, standing on a snowy rooftop. I want a unicorn hat :(]

Comment: The first rule of Winterbash: you do not talk about Winterbash!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203801/upcoming-winterbash-2013?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @MartijnPieters But I've been nice all year.. :(

Comment: @Habib More of an user's idea.. But it'd be nice.

Comment: `Any info on what we are getting for Christmas this year?`  186 questions about hats, again.

Comment: -1 no freehand circles

Comment: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5213/haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaats

Comment: Really looking forward to the end of year! One small point - the Southern Hemisphere SO community is currently experiencing summer :)

Comment: This time we'll get bitcoins :P

Comment: @StuartC `javascript:void(document.body.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(180deg)")`

Answer (score 44):

[image]

You're getting secrets. For now. :)

Keep an eye out on [our blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/); we'll make an announcement there when we're ready to share the details publicly.

Comment: Awwww alright then :P Not even a little sneak peak ? ^_^

Comment: Which secrets are we getting? :P

Comment: @TravisJ maybe the cat image is the secret, we all get cats for Christmas

Comment: @psubsee2003 - But I want mine meow. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I don't want a cat. I want a unicorn.

Comment: @JDB it might be a unicorn, he just put his horn aside for the bath. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLGZ.png :P

Comment: Been to the blog. Does the top bar count as a 'hat'? We want user hats, not site hats! :)

Comment: The cat has hypnotized me, I can't leave this page and can't stop looking at it.

Comment: . . . NEEDS MOAR HAT!

Comment: Could be anything, including the proverbial kittychen sink.  My guessing here inclines toward ground, not figure: sinks galore, not...

Answer (score 37):

Since it's [not really](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11706/math-se-and-winter-bash-2013) a secret anymore: Winter Bash 2013 will start on December 16th. Here's a little teaser, with apologies to [Marco](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131112/sklivvz) and [Laura](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166017/laura):

[image: Marco and Laura with hats]

<sup>(Yes, this year you'll be able to customize the hat's position on your avatar.)</sup>

Comment: Great! Thanks for the last line in the brackets!

Comment: You shouldn't apologise for such masterpieces.

Comment: It has leaked !

Comment: I see the MLP hat is a hidden hat. How do you get it? =oP

Comment: @crypticツ - Cannot do much for the MLP hat, but I should be able to at last help you getting the other hat.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, fine, [you can have hats again this year](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/)...