# Shouldn't I be a hipster?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

Based on the [timings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211715/150214) of [certain things](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146792/how-do-i-open-the-gates-in-yaga-shuras-lair), and by carefully watching the behaviour of [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146452/3610) [hipsters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146690/3610), I think I should [qualify](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldurs-gate-2-tob), but I don't seem to.

Should I be a hipster?

Comment: What defines a hipster - asking about Winter Bash before it was cool? But Winter Bash was always cool

Comment: @Pëkka Don't know about you but it's been positively freezing here for ages.

Comment: @MartijnPieters :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only are hip and cool when you've re-discovered the old fashion. *Anyone* can put on a retro-style glasses, but it is not hip until you've retroactively shown that it is retro!

There is a spoiler below, only read it if you are really cool and into these things.

> You must've created a *new* tag with a *new* question, then go and *add the tag to an older question*. Now you are hip because your use of the tag is totally retro.
>
>  You cannot create the tag by adding it to an existing post, it has to be created *with* the new question.

<sup><sub>There is a huge caveat: I don't actually *have* the hat yet, so this only speculation. This does fit observed behaviour.</sub></sup>

Comment: Yes, like Martijn has started this cool new trend of *holding* the headphones rather than wearing them on your head. I think I'm going to try that out sometime...

Comment: @animuson They're probably [Flips](https://www.flipsaudio.com/).

Comment: @TimStone: Flips are *sooo* yesterday. I use totally use Urbanears, man.

Comment: Sorry, but this time you're wrong.

Comment: @balpha: Cool, fine to be wrong; I haven't got the badge myself yet, but surely I am in the right direction?

Comment: @balpha Having worked out how hipster is awarded, aren't there certain *implications...?*

Comment: @fredley I have yet to see someone figure out how it's awarded. Also, Martijn has found out about other secret hats before.

Comment: @balpha But I know how Eureka is awarded, isn't that enough?