# Bounty description box design issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

I was starting bounty over [my this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184312/183757) and when I started writing description and its get over two lines its box get disturbed (and some text also interpreted wrong)

> [image: bounty box]

another example (`(` in first line and `w` in second line is added automatically):

[image: another]

I am using firefox 25.0, windows 7 and 1280 * 1024.

Comment: You need to type in it to make it happen

Comment: I get that all the time, welcome to the party.