# How to reopen a closed question by a moderator?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, historical-lock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

I answered the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591/what-wpf-books-would-you-recommend/9919#9919) about WPF books back in August 2008. I thought I'd be a good citizen and go and update my answer with some more books I've read since that time. However, the question has been locked and closed.

Now I realise this isn't the best question or answer. It's subjective; the answer was my opinion. That said, it seems to be a very useful answer for anyone that might be looking for information on WPF. In fact, if I search for "WPF book" on google, it's the first result. Yet I can't seem to update the answer. It seems to go against the very goals of the site - of having an updated, relevant, useful programming Q & A site.

Without getting too much into politics (I rarely visit Meta), I was wondering why such questions are marked as locked and closed, and what can be done to make these active again. From looking at this question [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-questio), it seems there is normally a link to vote to reopen - is the link missing because the question was closed by a moderator? If so, what can be done from here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the lock notice

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**[.]

Your answer was probably useful to a lot of people (that's partially why the question has been locked), but it's unlikely that it will get reopened.

> [...] it seems there is normally a link to vote to reopen - is the link missing because the question was closed by a moderator? If so, what can be done from here?

The link is missing because of the lock. This is also the only thing that prevents the question from getting **deleted**.

The lock can only be undone by a Moderator. Unless there's a major change in the site's policy, that's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the info on historical locks. I had missed the link to that part of the FAQ on the original question. It's interesting though - the FAQ states that historical locks should not be used if the question is being maintained. I can't maintain it with the lock. Chicken and Egg I guess. Even more interesting is the link from the historical lock to rule 3 from http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/ I'd interpret this question as something someone can learn from  or make them better at their job.

Comment: @brad it's a "let's make a list of X!" which may have been allowed in 2008 but has long since been deprecated with extreme prejudice network-wide.