# How to seek attention to reopen a closed question?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564200/aptana-studio-vs-netbeans-vs-eclipse-for-linux-any-single-ide-for-java-and-php) on Stack Overflow which has been closed and despite me amending it multiple times, I couldn't get 5 votes to reopen it. From the FAQs, I've learned that one moderator's vote is enough to reopen it, or 5 members having 3k+ reputation.

There are these questions already,

- [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)
- [How to reopen a closed question by a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138354/how-to-reopen-a-closed-question-by-a-moderator)

Is there any way to seek members (or Moderators') attention to reopen a closed question or at least get comments on what more amendment is require to open that question?

(Wondering if flagging the question is an option to seek moderators attention to reopen/review it?)

---

The reason why my question was closed,

> recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

But if you read over the question now, it doesn't emphasize on **which** but **how** to do a thing!

Comment: After an edit or initial reopen vote the post goes into the re-open voting queue. I always look at the comments on such posts, make sure your comments explain why the post should be reopened if it wasn't edited to address the original closing reason.

Comment: If it wasn't reopened through the reopen queue, I guess people didn't feel it was worth reopening.

Comment: However, your post still looks like a tool recommendation to me, I would not vote to reopen that post.

Comment: WIDR...i want to know if there is a way to execute 2 languages in one of the IDE's mentioned, i am not asking `what IDE should i use`, i have put a comment below the question mentioning *why it should be re-opened*...what other change should i do as per your opinion????

Comment: Richard Tingle already commented on that point; he's asking why the questions you refer to don't answer that question.

Comment: yes..m following-on, on it sir :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters : seems Richard voted to open the question...any way i can change your mind to vote in my favor!!

Comment: I would simply ask a new question that doesn't depend on choosing a tool to answer it.  Figure out which IDE you're going to use, and then ask your question about that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can draw attention to a closed post:

- Editing a closed post will result in it appearing in the re-open review queue for people who can reopen posts.
- You could flag the post with a custom reason to get a moderator to look at but this is not the preferred method to gain attention to your post.

Comment: @OGHaza Don't avoid editing something if the edit's worthwhile and won't get rejected. :/

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore, I have edit privileges, but if I think a question isn't going to see the light of day again anyway I leave it alone.

Comment: I believe edits send a question to the reopen queue if the question is *on hold* (first five days of closure), but not if it's transitioned from "on hold" to "closed".