# How do I appeal an "exact duplicate" close?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Re. [How do I robustly parse malformed CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733076/how-do-i-robustly-parse-malformed-csv)

This question is not an exact duplicate of the one linked. That one assumes that all fields are quoted, that quoting is consistent, that there are no within-field linebreaks, etc. I read that question before posting this, and it was inadequate.

However, I don't see any way to appeal the close. :-/

Comment: It's also not currently closed, but this itself is a fairly generic question. Although, I think this question might be a duplicate.

Comment: @TartLevee Looks like someone edited it (as well as my comment directed at the closing mod).

Comment: The answer to this question is outdated and missing information relevant today (e.g. editing within five days), and dispenses bad advice (flagging for moderator attention is no longer preferred). Better, more detailed advice is available in our FAQs [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) and [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/377214).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Edit the question with more information to clearly show that it's not a duplicate. You'll probably want to provide a link to the not-a-duplicate
2. Leave a comment to the effect of "I've edited my question to show why it's not a duplicate of X"
3. Vote to Re-Open
4. (optional) flag for Moderator attention and use the "Other" option to explain that it's not a duplicate

Remember: "Closed" is not an end state; it just means that no new answers can be posted. In most cases, you have a couple of days to improve the question before people will (can) vote to delete it. It's expected that you'll use that time to improve the question.

If the above fails, you can also post a bounty on the duplicate question to try to get a better answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you've looked up a similar question before posting yours, it's a good idea to mention that in your question and explain why it's different. That way people know you've researched first. Say something like:

> I saw this question `<link>` and it doesn't solve my problem because `<explanation>`.