# Is there something wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, specific-question

I'm new to programming, and I'm new to the site, and I have asked a few questions about [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) which I am learning as my first language, (besides HTML). When I learn a new language, like I did with HTML I like to make a program or website while I'm still learning. So I asked a question hoping to get good answers, which I got, but I got downvoted twice. Is there something wrong with my question?

This is it: [Variable nesting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867075/variable-nesting-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to put things in perspective, 2 down votes is not such a big deal.. It's only the opinion of two users...

One thing I can see (but IMO not worthy of a down vote from *me*) is your lack of capitalizing the word "I". It should always be capitalized.

One more thing the *might* have drawn in some negative votes is the fact (an admission) that you are actually asking the same question twice...

> I asked a simialar question to this but it got deleted since i was unclear.

You can always edit your existing question to add clarification. There is no real need to ask a new question. I'm not saying these downvotes are valid or invalid. All I am trying to do is to give this situation an objective perspective.

Comment: My old question got closed so I couldnt edit it, I guess I have to capitalize my I's more then? And my other question really wasn't a replica, this one is a lot clearer.

Comment: You **can** edit your own closed question. A question can always be reopened if the problems are fixed...

Comment: Well, its to late now, but how would i reopen it ? Like I said im new to stack overflow.

Comment: @nic - not to sure how much I could help you there because python is not my specialty. I can however give you some links related to [closed questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) and how to [reopen them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).

Comment: ok thanks, i'll just be more carefull.

Answer (score 3):

**I agree with Lix's answer, but here are some more things to consider:**

### **Tips to Include Code in Questions:**

- When posting code, make sure it's readable. In general, it's wise to use variable names that are descriptive. This helps not only you and other people who have to work with your code, like colleagues or a teacher, but also members of Stack Overflow. Variables with meaningful names help us understand the problem much better. Remember, we're not compilers! :)
- Use code comments in your code. You should do this for similar reasons as you would for using meaningful variable names. I use comments to help me remember what a specific block of code is doing, why I did what I did in cases where I'm using a hack, or if I want to point out something important to colleagues or future maintainers. You can also use comments to indicate to Stack Overflow users where you think your problem might be or to highlight points that are important to understanding the problem.
- Looking at the comments, it's obvious that some people's first instinct was to just use an array, list, or some other data structure, which is quite reasonable. This is why it's important to tell the community what you've already tried so far, or why an obvious answer wouldn't work. Imagine answering a question with what you think would be an obvious answer and then getting this as a response:

> i know the difference between a list and a variable, i need a variable, did you read the question and i do know the basics i've read all about lists

In your question, you still haven't indicated why a list or array won't work. Use the edit link below your post to clarify in the question body itself.

### **Closure vs Deletion:**

Lastly, you said your question got deleted. If you're referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773797/how-to-make-the-name-of-a-variable-a-variable-in-python then no, it didn't get deleted; it was closed.

On Stack Exchange, we close questions that don't fit the guidelines in hopes that the question can be edited and improved before reopening. Unlike most forums where your post must be reviewed before allowing answers, here users can post outright, and only if there are problems do we put it into the queue.

> ## closed as not a real question
>
> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. ***For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).***
>
> - Italicized emphasis is mine.

Whenever a question is closed, you should edit it and improve it. Questions that are downvoted and closed contribute to an automated ban if you continue down that path, so it's a good idea to try to make existing posts better instead of simply writing new ones.

If you ever need specific help improving a post, you can always ask here on Meta SO, just be sure to use a constructive tone and make it clear you're seeking help; rants typically don't end well. There are people here who enjoy helping others improve their posts. :)  Good luck!