# How should I approach valid answers on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, review, closed-questions

While reviewing Late Answers/ First Posts, I usually come across valid answers on closed questions.

What approach should I take in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question as a question could be closed for very different reasons. 
Generally, I would consider if the answer really brings value.

For example, when a question is a duplicate, it may happen that

- the answer is clearly better than all the answers on the original question, for example it gives the correct solution that no one found before (in this case I usually vote to reopen)
- the answer, being more specific to OP's problem, helps when it might be difficult to get the problem using only the original question

And don't forget that looking at the answers sometimes proves that a question wasn't understood by people closing it and that it shouldn't have been closed.

Regarding first posts, one of the goals is to educate the poster. In this situation the fact that the question is closed doesn't change anything if you point a problem on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

From the standpoint of reviewing answers, there's really no difference between regular questions and questions that have been closed.  Closed questions can't have new answers posted, but you can still take any of the review actions: vote it up or down, edit it, leave a comment, or flag for moderator review.

Comment: At the same time, is it really worth spending time reviewing content for a closed question?

Comment: Thats the same i want to know, is there any point. What is the need of keeping the closed questions on the review panel? If we are considering the question as not fit, then answers to these also become irrelevant.

Comment: @UnniKris Closed answers are still searchable, people still look at them, and are helped by them (or not).  If a question is *deleted*, then it really is persona non grata.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably most important to take into account that closed questions can be **[reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)**.

From this perspective, it is completely legitimate to perform review actions same way for posts in closed and open questions.

---

<sub>One can also consider chances of particular question to be reopened, [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/155561/revisions) questions have more chances for that than others. But I for one typically avoid that because doing routine review actions is easier than pondering on fuzzy guesses.</sub>