# How can I petition to reopen a question which was - in my opinion - incorrectly closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

I asked a question, which was closed as a duplicate of another question. It isn't a duplicate, it asks something similar, but not answered by the alleged duplicate. It seems to me the closers didn't take enough time to understand my rather esoteric question.

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855700/suppress-javac-warning/13862308).

Is there a way to petition a question to be reopened when one believes it has been incorrectly closed?

Comment: That question isn't closed.

Comment: @Mysticial, thanks for pointing that out. I posted the wrong link. It is now fixed.

Comment: It already has 4 reopen votes on it. So it'll be reopened soon.

Comment: And now it's re-opened. :)

Comment: It's not a duplicate @hims056. The OP has enough rep to vote to reopen they're asking how do you get others to do the same.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Please read the accepted answer on that duplicate question (by `@random`) See `Comments to reopen`.

Comment: Thanks to whoever do the final necessary reopen vote. It would be good if there was a standard "please consider for reopen" request.

Comment: @SteveMcLeod - Read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/187824)