# Multiple Duplicate-Marks

Tags: support, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

Why does the infamous "Marked as duplicate by" message tend to have multiple users in it? Is it marked as a duplicate once many people mark it as one, or do other people just mark it as well to ensure its integrity?

This is an example:

> marked as duplicate by jadarnel27, animuson, Toon Krijthe, Bo Persson, Austin Henley Feb 9 at 0:44

Comment: [It takes five close votes to close a question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). Exception: mods can unilaterally close a question.

Comment: @Luke Oh okay, thank you. I had wondered about this for a while. You can use that as an answer if wanted.

Comment: You have to have 3000 reputation or more to vote to close, by the way. It requires 5 users so that people can't just go close everything for fun or because they are angry or something. Also, you only get 50 closevotes per day. (I've never used them all up though :P)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It takes five close votes to close a question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close). The only exception to this rule is that mods can unilaterally close a question. In the same manner, it takes 5 reopen votes to reopen a closed question. Again, a mod can single-handedly reopen a question.

More info on closing and reopening found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/192187) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415/192187), respectively.