# How come this question is being closed as off-topic?

Tags: support, off-topic, facebook

Regarding Stack Overflow question *[Facebook - 'Misconfigured app. Sorry, the details for cannot be displayed because'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460216)*:

How is this question off-topic?

Facebook is redirecting us to Stack Overflow for asking our questions and problems. Because of that I went there to ask about my problem. But my question was closed.

Comment: *Where* is Facebook still redirecting to Stack Overflow? Just because Facebook is pointing to us, does not make every question about Facebook on topic.

Comment: It's off topic because "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: [so] is for programming questions. And this question isn't a programming issue. QED -> it is off-topic.

Comment: it is not off topic and facebook redirects to stackoverflow. https://developers.facebook.com/support/community/

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Saying **some** questions can be asked on SO does not in any way mean **all** questions can be

Comment: Why is it **not** off-topic? What makes it on-topic? And that FB links to us means **nothing**.

Comment: @Oded: the confusion may be coming from this link: https://developers.facebook.com/support, which makes it sound like there's some official collaboration between the two to allow for questions that "Ask for Help" (to quote the title).  Regardless, (as you said) that still is no excuse for making that off-topic.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Well aware of that page and link. And we _used_ to have a branded, filtered view of [so] for people coming from there. Doesn't mean questions asked by those coming from there should be held to a lower standard.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Additionally, the OP is a long time user of SO and should know better.

Comment: Please take some time and review the edits on that post. Don't make more posts until you no longer require such edits.

Comment: My answer tells you specifically why these questions are usually on-topic, and I've cast the first re-open.  Good Luck.

Comment: You guys are wasting your breath:  a number of us tried explaining the same thing to the user [in a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345306/having-music-in-the-asp-net-game-continuous-audio-playing) and all ended up getting serially-downvoted as a result.

Comment: man when people type that question to the google, they come to find answer on stack overflow. but u say it is off topic. unbelievable.

Comment: Looks like it got deleted, probably unilaterally.  I feel sorry for those developers who have to deal with the appcenter.

Comment: @LanceRoberts just fyi, you are not correct about how it was deleted. Not a single diamond mod was involved.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, thanks for the info.

Comment: same question as mine. 0 down votes. mine got 15 and after deleted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576347/facebook-sdk-app-center-does-not-link-to-app-detail-page

Answer (score 14):

Stack Overflow is independent from Facebook. There is no relation between the two and what the Facebook developers page tells you to do, does not give you any advantage or rights within and over the SO internal rules.

While some Facebook related questions are valid on SO because they are specific programmatic questions, it does not make **every** Facebook related question on topic. SO is specifically about programming which is all defined within the [help-centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

*Consider yourself a guest* - feel free to ask a question but do not get upset because it gets closed. And if it does, that means at least 5 community members thought your question was not suitable for this site. Instead of starting to argue, take 5 minutes to calm down and read the rules *or understand the closure reason*.

AFAIK, you have three options:

- Edit your question so it fits within the scope specified in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Make sure you you follow SSCCE.org and visit the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to make your question better. Then submit your vote for [reopening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).
- If your question still isn't suitable, try to find a better Stack Exchange site for you question. Consider Super User for example (*follow the same procedure for asking - meaning make sure your question is on topic*)
- Ask somewhere else.

---

Also, this normally should be enough to understand and take steps

[image]

Comment: man when people type that question to the google, they come to find answer on stack overflow. but u say it is off topic. unbelievable.

Comment: @monster since when does Google define what is on-topic here?

Comment: Don't you dare question the GOOGLE @AndrewBarber!

Comment: @Bart It's OK. It's not like they have the whole Intarwebz saved somewhere and can easily find any such mentions. Errr....

Comment: same question as mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576347/facebook-sdk-app-center-does-not-link-to-app-detail-page

Comment: related: **[Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/839601)**

Answer (score -10):

The help for topics states that one of the criteria is:

> **software tools commonly used by programmers**

**Obviously, for Facebook developers, the appcenter is a tool that they have to use, so questions about it are relevant to Stack Overflow.**

The argument against might be the next bullet point, which states:

> practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development

since while you're understandably unable to post relevant code, I'm not sure there is enough information to make this answerable, but I would have to defer that to Facebook experts.