# I find this questions similar, but could not say they are duplicates

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I just looked over one of my old questions and came across this:

[Python: Why operator "is" and "==" are sometimes interchangeable for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705379/python-why-operator-is-and-are-sometimes-interchangeable-for-strings)

Now looking more in-depth over the two questions a few justifications why it might not be a  duplicate of the suggested question:

- my question is specific the other one is more general, it asks a detailed behavior on a given example against a general behavior of the operators in the other question;
- my question is catching in the answer a behavior of the python interpreter (CPython uses same identities for short strings ) that is nowhere to be found in the answers of the other question.

Can this question be considered for reopening and not be considered as a duplicate ?

Comment: I like how your example also seems to be about exactly matching something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, your question is definitely a duplicate of the more general question.

The other question answers your specific points as to *why* Python strings sometimes test true for both equality *and* identity.

Moreover, the more general question is more useful to future visitors *because* it is more general. Chances are that others run into the same general problem, less so that they hit the specific wording you gave it.

At best, your question is a duplicate of multiple questions; the one it closed against now, plus [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce) and  [Python string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541404/python-string-interning). As your question was closed as duplicate when the Community user still added the dupe targets manually, I've gone ahead and added these two to the list at the top.

Comment: I agree that at best is a dupicate of two questions, also I edited the original question because the single double quotes game whas confusing and hard to read. Thanks for clarifing.