# Should I edit an [on-hold] question, and my edit can't get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, edits

Can I still edit an [on-hold] question, despite my edit can't get it reopened?

For example here's a post which is already closed (and I can't find a real example), the code format is wrong. Should I edit it and correct the code format?

I know that my edit will let it enter the Reopen Votes Queue, and I also know it should be still leave closed.

From [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/305595) on MSE:

> You can edit the post so that it fits the site topic or remove the points of offense if so marked. The close reason, while not always accurate, should point you in the right direction of what to fix.

But from our [Help Center > Privileges > Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!

So I think that I can make the post better, but I don't want it enter the Reopen Votes Queue since I can't make it on-topic. Should I still edit it or leave it there?

Comment: No, the post doesn't matter at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the closed question is scored at zero and has no answers, then don't bother - it'll be destroyed automatically in a few days.

If the question is going to stick around and **has one or more good answers** (i.e. it resulted in the sharing of some knowledge), then I'd say it's a good thing to clarify and improve it. It's not a terrible thing to put a non-reopenable question through the reopen queue if you're actually improving something. Of course, the improvements had better be substantial - fixing typos and grammar, even if such fixes would normally be welcomed, wouldn't be too useful if they don't **clarify the meaning of the question** and **contribute to the usefulness of the good, existing answers**.

As mentioned in the comments, questions can only go through the reopen queue once. Therefore, if there is hope for a question and you edit it, **it is your duty to repair it**. Again, though, if a question can never be made acceptable (and you're sure about that), substantial yet non-reopening edits are OK.

Comment: Note that you have *one shot* for going thru the reopen queue. If the first edit made to a closed question doesn't make it reopenable, it's too late since further edits won't push the question into the reopen queue again.

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks, that's good to know. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, understand :)