# Provide a path for low-rep users to get a successfully edited closed question reopened

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

[image: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."]

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

If you're lower rep and you don't know what the reopen link is as a result, then it's very easy to read this as "it's closed, but will be reopened if the reason for closure is edited away". My edit was approved, and I didn't understand why the question wasn't reopened until I remembered from another SE site that reopening is a separate thing, and a privilege that I don't have access to on SO.

Something's wrong here. The wording does not clearly state that I can edit a post, but editing has nothing to do with reopening.

And now that I remember that distinction (to be clear, I only know the distinction because I'm high-rep on another site; I didn't figure it out through SO's UI), I'm not sure what the path forward is. I flagged it and tried to explain this but I have no way of checking the outcome of the flag that I know of. I added a comment in hopes that OP or someone else could see it and vote to reopen, but there's no feedback there either. Future visitors will see that the question is closed, and they'll likely assume that it was closed for its current wording and thus see no reason to reopen.

If I see another question I can edit for the purpose of reopening, why would I do so if I have less than 3000 rep?

Comment: "*The wording does not clearly state that I can edit a post, but editing has nothing to do with reopening.*" That would be incorrect. A post gets reopened is either if it is edited to correct the problems or if you manage to convince people that the question was incorrectly closed. So generally speaking, editing is necessary, but not *sufficient* for reopening. And I don't think the text in question suggests a guarantee of reopening if the question is edited.

Comment: "*If I see another question I can edit for the purpose of reopening, why would I do so if I have less than 3000 rep?*" To make it valid for reopening. The problems aren't going to fix themselves, and it's not going to be reopened if it doesn't get fixed.

Comment: [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question) explains the already-existing pathways a low-rep user can use to get a post reopened.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog Wait, is that the expected thing for a low-rep user - search Meta.SE if you don't know how to do something? Why have that last sentence in the yellow box at all then?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the very first (and only the very first) edit to a post, after its closure, sends the post to the "reopen queue" where users with sufficient reputation will review the question for reopening.  Hence, the first edit, whether by the asker, or another user, is the most important edit, and needs to take care to  get it "right": correcting the post so that it addresses and overcomes the reason for closure.

While the first edit may send a post to the reopen queue for evaluation, it doesn't guarantee the post will be reopened. Enough reviewers must vote to reopen in order to reopen it. If most reviewers vote NOT to reopen, it leaves the reopen queue.

Subsequent edits will NOT send the post to the reopen review queue.  They might bump the question to the forefront, for users who follow the *active* home page.

It may be that your suggested edit was not the first edit, and so did not initiate a review by users as to whether to reopen or not.

Answer (score 3):

> The wording does not clearly state that I can edit a post, **but editing has nothing to do with reopening**.

That's not an entirely true premise (emphasis mine).

Editing is the very first step you need to get a question reopened:

- Editing bumps the question up to be seen at the *active home page* and sends it to the *reopen queue*.
- If others think that the question is now eglible for reopening they can vote as such.

Comment: If I am not mistaken.  A question is only ever put into the reopen queue once, based on the age of that question (that is being asked about), that is likely to have happen at least once in the last 6 years.  A question can be voted to be reopen, it just requires 5 users, but there isn't a queue for questions like that after the first nomination.