# Why is my question still unclear after lots of edits according to suggestions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, suggested-edits, reopen-closed

My [question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140045/am-i-being-used-more-than-my-job-role-as-a-graphic-designer/140056?noredirect=1#comment451831_140056) is marked as unclear for 2-3 days. I've edited it a lot and made more specific, answerable. But it's still marked unclear.

Comment: You should ask this on [meta.workplace.se] because that is the site whose users placed your question On Hold.

Comment: Objectively speaking, it is overly long and confusing, there are too many parenthesis and as a result the question appears [woolly](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woolly) and meandering. I tried editing it into shape, there's still more that could be done but it's a start. The edit also needs to be approved.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've accepted the edit with a bit changes.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [question timeline](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/140045/timeline), there is no completed [Reopen Votes review queue item](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats). The [main review queue page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review) indicates there are four open items; your question is one of them. That means you'll have to have a little bit more patience; users aren't monitoring the review queues 24/7. We're all volunteers here :) If, after a few days, you do see a completed review (you don't get a notification of this), you can try one of the other avenues to get your question reopened, e.g. by posting a [[reopen-request]](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reopen-request) on The Workplace Meta.

For more information, see the FAQ [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36423/295232)

Comment: Your answer is a little bit difficult to understand here. Do you mean my question is fine and will be opened soon?

Comment: @Vikas no we mean that it's too early to tell whether it will be reopened or not.

Comment: I don't know if it's fine, just that you need to wait a little bit. See the updated answer.

Comment: Okay, how can I learn about "the question is reviewed" things? I just don't know about this feature.

Comment: It's open now. Please can you tell me what happens in the background? Can I see this how it works?

Comment: Great :) You can read the FAQ I linked to, that contains a lot of information