# How do I answer a comment that was made to a deleted question?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions, deleted-questions

[A question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053186/transform-point-in-the-poincar%C3%A9-disc-to-point-in-tile) I posted a while ago was closed because it "needs details or clarity", and it is now deleted. While I think the question is clear, a user posted the comment "Could you be a little more specific and precise in your question?". Since I don't know what it is that they thought was unclear, I thought I was going to ask them about it, in order to clarify that, but I see that comments are "disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews".

So, how can I ask the user what they thought needed to be clarified in my question, now when comments are disabled? How can I find out what details I need to add so that the question can be reopened/undeleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Comment: @MrMythical Do you know that the answer to my question is in there somewhere (and in which section of the answer, in that case), or do you want me to read through the entire answer in order to be able to answer your question? No, I don't immediately see that it answers my question.

Comment: The answer to your question is actually here, in [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question). If you can't vote to reopen, comment on, or edit your question to submit for review because it's deleted, you can post a question on the site's per-site meta (in this case [meta.math.se]) to ask for further details.

Comment: @MrMythical I've read that FAQ and can't find where this is answered in its answer.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ah I swear I saw something about comments in there before

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thank you, now I know how to proceed if this happens again. Meanwhile, I just posted a [new question](orthographic projection of the hyperboloid model onto the xy-plane) which I tried to make more concrete in order to make it easier to understand my question.

Comment: Hello, if the person and yourself are active in chat that's another avenue; if it's lacking such details or clarity that it's deleted you might want to see what is required for a good question on that site (their meta, in the FAQ), rather than trying to ask first.