# Why are alerts not given to the original poster when their question is closed?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please notify us when a question we ask or answer is closed or reopened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/please-notify-us-when-a-question-we-ask-or-answer-is-closed-or-reopened)
>   [Send a Stack Exchange notification when a question gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-a-stack-exchange-notification-when-a-question-gets-closed)

Notice that I never get an alert in my inbox that a question has been closed, why is this?

**UPDATE >> RESPONSE-TO-CLOSE:** It's not the same question as those linked to above which are feature-request. My question is a request for support; a mod, Yannis Rizos, changed it to a feature-request when he migrated the question. My question is why I don't get a notice, meaning there must be a reason why SE has never added the feature, and I would like to know what the reason is.

Comment: Good question, I don't have an answer.

Comment: This is a good question. Not only should closing give a notice, but any state change (edit, conversion to wiki, closing, answer, comment) to a post that you "own" (a wiki post you are the highest contributor to, a post that you created) should probably generate a notification, I think. Perhaps there's a discussion on Meta.StackOverflow about this - I haven't checked.

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: I assumed there was an existing answer, which is why I didn't post it as a feature-request. If you want to change it to a feature-request and move it to Meta Stack Overflow, that's fine with me.

Comment: Related feature request: [Please notify us when a question we ask or answer is closed or reopened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3432/please-notify-us-when-a-question-we-ask-or-answer-is-closed-or-reopened)

Comment: @jadarnel27 Related, but I don't think duplicate. That one is asking for a banner at the top of the screen while this is about an inbox-delivered message. For a banner, you need to be on the proper site. Inbox notifications are on any site.

Comment: Actually, the other question is not asking for a banner. As I see it, both the questions are asking for a notification; which notification will be implemented depends from SE staff's decisions.

Comment: @mmyers: It's not the same question, my question is a request for support - a mod, Yannis Rizos, changed it to a feature-request when he migrated the question. My question is why I don't get a notice, meaning there must be a reason why SE has never added the feature, and I would like to know what the reason is. Thanks!

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) and events.