# Lengthy answer -> bit bucket when question is closed mid-edit

Tags: feature-request

I tend to write lengthy answers and that takes some time. On several occasions now I've been in the midst of writing such an answer when the question is modded on-hold or closed. When that occurs, when I go to post the answer I get a message and my work disappears.

This is *extremely* frustrating. I understand that different users will have different opinions on whether a particular question should be closed, but the act of doing so should not simply throw another user's work in the garbage.

I'm aware of [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133660/notify-upvoters-and-answerers-when-a-question-is-closed), which is certainly related, but that thread is discussing things that have *already* been posted. The end result is similar, your great answer disappears, but that thread is concerned with the *notification* issues, not the problem of the material disappearing.

Possible solutions:

- Allow the answer to be saved, just block future edits - Seems like the simplest solution?
- Indicate to the mods that an answer is enroute - make an answer the equivalent of an open vote?
- Indicate an ongoing close process to both the editor and mod - at least this way there's no surprises?
- Other solutions?

Comment: Simply don't invest in questions which are likely to be closed as being _off-topic_ or _duplicates_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - how do you know that will happen if you start writing before  any such votes were cast?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz By learning what types of questions are on topic on the site you're on.

Comment: _"how do you know that will happen"_ By better knowing the sites policies for _on-topic_. questions

Comment: @Servy - I already did that.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Apparently not, if you aren't able to tell what questions merit closure and are trying to answer them.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Another indication would be that the question carries close votes already. The exact rep needed to have that privilege is site specific. Downvotes on questions also might be an indicator. However the DV cultures at specific sites are also varying.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - The last example had no downvotes or flags when I started editing.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Another (but still risky) strategy is, you post a FGITW answer containing the TL;DR; gist of your answer, to clearly show that the question is well answerable and _on-topic_. In a second step you edit to flesh it out in more detail.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - but again, this would require me to know in advance that someone will vote it down *in the future*. Or are you suggesting everyone do this all the time?!?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Blocking others from DV/CV'ing doesn't sound like a good idea though. Just be sure, if you really go to invest efforts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I'm not suggesting blocking DV CV, I don't see anywhere I said anything remotely like that.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz So what exactly do you expect? A feature that allows you to save your markup offline? What's hindering you to use Notepad? All those indication could already be tracked having the question open in a separate browser tab.

Comment: Upvote the question maybe if you find it good. If a question is upvoted that is an indication in my case to watch somewhere else for VTC, as anyhow the VTC queue is already enough big (but don't upvote crap please)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Save the edit. Why not? What's the downside I'm missing here?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Why not saving it offline as I proposed to you? You may go to comment and/or reopen vote the closed question later. _"Why not?"_ Because it's not worth to invest SE Devs time for things you can easily manage yourself already.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - Hmmm. Should I upvote everything I intend to answer? Actually, that doesn't seem entirely bad. In fact, perhaps beginning an answer should do that automatically?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Answering a question doesn't automatically make it good.  For example, see this question.  I disagree with your premise, but I have answered it.  And downvoted it.  I don't want to be automatically upvoting things.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - The text area is cleared out when you try to post. And there is no indication this will occur.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz So take a copy to an open Notebook file before clicking that button. What's the problem?

Comment: @fbueckert sorry, badly wrote it, I just mean the OP should learn the site culture to be able to detect what to not answer, and while he do so, he should just answer on question that are in the positive in worst case

Comment: If the question was closed within 5 minutes and your answer is on the page, you can remove the disabled attribute from the submit element, and submit your answer. This should not be a pattern though, if you are constantly writing answers to questions that get closed, consider that you are probably trying to answer the wrong questions.

Comment: @TravisJ - can you explain how one would do that? Are you suggesting editing the HTML response? I'm not sure that would be considered legit.

Comment: Could you link to one of these questions? I'd really like to see how fast it was closed and for what reason...

Comment: The server doesn't actually block answers to closed questions until 4 hours after closure; the disabling you see is purely client-side. You can open up Developer Tools to do what Travis J said.

Comment: I had this happen to me once. But, as I was in the middle of composing an answer, my browser got a push update and I was notified that the question was now closed. I knew at that point to abandon my answer. I wonder if you have fallen victim to unfortunately timing, or if you're not getting notified in a similar fashion (for whatever reason).

Comment: @JasonBassford - that definitely did NOT happen for me. Chrome on Win and Safari on Mac, what are you using?

Comment: I use Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Hmmm. Can anyone else confirm that they got the updates pushed? Maybe I should ask the developers?

Comment: In fact, I always get push updates when new comments or answers are added, or when questions or answers are edited.

Comment: I get notified of comments and answers. Note below: CVs do not send updates, mystery solved.

Answer (score 5):

You present these as possible solutions:

> Allow the answer to be saved, just block future edits - Seems like the simplest solution?

That would defeat the entire purpose of closing a question.  It's supposed to *prevent* answers because there's a problem with the question.

> Indicate to the mods that an answer is enroute - make an answer the equivalent of an open vote?

Who says you haven't walked away from the computer?  Are we supposed to just wait to do anything with it until everyone is able to chime in?  Quite often off-topic questions are going to be popular, too; you'll have a ton of people trying to answer.  That doesn't make them any less off-topic, but this would prevent them from being closed.

> Indicate an ongoing close process to both the editor and mod - at least this way there's no surprises?

You can see that if you're the asker or can vote to close.  It's not updated in realtime, but it shouldn't have to be.  If you want to answer a question that's downvoted or has close votes, you run the risk of not being able to post the answer you've worked on.  Think hard on whether the risk is worth it.

> Other solutions?

Your best bet, if a question is worth keeping and answering, but is attracting down and close votes, is to **edit** the question into shape before answering.  Do your best to clarify and keep it concise.  If you are not able to do so, then perhaps you need to ask yourself if it shouldn't actually be closed.

Comment: "It's not updated in realtime, but it shouldn't have to be." - I am unclear on this. Can you explain? Consider the case: a question is new, it has no DVs or CVs. I begin to edit. DVs and CVs start to pile up. Why should I not be told of this?

Comment: You'll see up and down votes.  It's close votes you won't see.  I'm not sure of the logic behind that, to be honest.  If a question is going to get closed, you're going to be seeing a decent number of downvotes going on.  That should be your signal to perhaps double-check the question, and see if perhaps it might need some improvement.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you are saying. I went back to check the only one I could find and it had only one DV. That doesn't strike me as "decent", but YMMV.