# Lots of tags breaks mobile responsive layout

Tags: bug, tags, design, responsive-design

I really hope this is a duplicate.

---

Here is a screenshot:

[image: wrong]

When a post has lots of tags on the mobile responsive layout ('full site' in the footer), they don't wrap round and you end up with horizontal scroll bars.

#### Expected

The tags wrap nicely onto the next row.

#### Actual

They don't.

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Spevacus! I was searching for mobile only, but that one is on desktop which is why I couldn't find it.

Comment: No problem! This dupe will hopefully raise awareness, so thank *you* for posting!