# Tags aren't wrapped

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design

When I go to a question on a mobile phone, I see that the tags are not wrapped so that a horizontal scrollbar appears over the whole page. See below.

[image]

This issue appears on every SE site except Stack Overflow. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S10e.

Comment: It looks like this happens on stack overflow too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859767/react-native-reanimated-v2-scale-opacity-withrepeat.

Comment: No repro, for me it's wrapping just fine. What device do you have?

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I'm using Samsung Galaxy S10e with Android 11.

Comment: OS is less relevant, I'll edit the device into the question.

Comment: I can repro as well @ShadowWizardisVaccinating. Using Huawei P20 Pro. Using Chrome on Android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The div containing tags for a question doesn't reflow, causing layout issues for questions with long/many tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354575/the-div-containing-tags-for-a-question-doesnt-reflow-causing-layout-issues-for)