# Alignment of tags in posts

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

Today I saw a post in the review list.  There were 5 tags and all were long tags. The last tag overlapped the **link**.

I was about to take a screenshot of the post, but it got edited.

[image]

So, I posted a post to check the alignment in Math SE with some long tags.

[image]

This time the last tag name got hidden behind **The Overflow Blog** block.

So it would be nice if the tags get automatically adjusted to the next line, for example with 4 in the first line and the remaining one in the next line (this post).

High rep users in Math SE can have a [look](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955805/kindly-wait-this-is-a-post-to-check-the-alignment-of-tags-will-be-deleted) at the post

Comment: This is also annoying on mobile when tags spill off the screen.

Comment: Yep, [it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVL7W.png)  :(

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358326/tags-arent-wrapped