# Visual bug related to long tag names

Tags: bug, user-interface

Seeing this bug on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/634101/limits-of-de-broglies-equation-and-wavefunction), attaching the photo of it

[image]

As you see, the tags extend into the "Related" questions area.

Here's what it looks like if I don't bring in the window (I did that after realizing something was off with the styling)
[image]

So the right edge of the tag is right up against "Related"

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can’t find the related question right now.

Comment: Are you on a mobile, or do you have a different screen resolution?   I'm seeing this around the 1150 px area.

Comment: This is on a MacBook Pro 15", 2880 × 1800. I noticed that "states-of-matter" was very close to "Related", so brought in the right edge of the window a bit to get the result show in the image.

Comment: ... and if you don't bring in the window?

Comment: Then the right edge of the tag is right next to the "R" in related, enough to notice that something's off with the styling (which is what prompted me bringing in the window).