# Long tag list overflows and is hidden behind Community Bulletin and other sidebar widgets or truncated

Tags: bug, tags, responsive-design

The MathOverflow question [Textbooks or lecture notes about mean field games](https://mathoverflow.net/q/397017/70594) has five rather long tags. On the question list page, such a tag list is wrapped onto two lines, but the Q&A page does not do this, causing the last tag to be partially hidden behind the Community Bulletin (or other sidebar widgets):

[image]

On small screens, the list is truncated as well:

[image]:

Comment: Ah, I knew this has already been reported! [The div containing tags for a question doesn't reflow, causing layout issues for questions with long/many tags](/q/354575/289905). This may be a regression, but the other linked questions are pretty recent, too. (Found via a duplicate among the first 15 results of this search: [\[bug\] tag overflow is:q url:"stack.imgur"](/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bbug%5D%20tag%20overflow%20is%3aq%20url%3a%22stack.imgur%22).)